# Spans vertical align with float

Tags: html, css, position, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a problem with vertically align 3 spans inside a div. It's easy to achieve, but vertical align doesn't work when i use float. I want that lightblue bar to be vertically centered. Code:

```css
.container {
}
.text-1 {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.bar {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  height: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}
.text-2 {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text-1">Text 1</span>
  <span class="bar">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="text-2">Text 2</span>
</div>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5cm4mn1b/)

Comment: So why do you still use `float`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block;` along with `vertical-align: middle;` on your `<span>` elements instead of float. This way they are positioned next to each other too and you can apply the vertical alignment:

```css
.container span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.text-1 {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.bar {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}
.text-2 {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text-1">Text 1</span>
  <span class="bar">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="text-2">Text 2</span>
</div>
```